# Ionic2 - Login and then Side menu

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating an **App with Ionic2** and the requirement is - 
- the app when first loaded will show a Log In page and when logged in 
- will have a Side-Menu enabled pages

The starter project shows that the Side Menu as the root of the app and loads first before any other page is open - then it loads the other related pages.

How can I build an app that Loads Log In page first and then set the Side Menu as the main navigation and never shows up the Log In screen??

I did this with ionic 1 but not being able to figure out with ionic2

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution would be to disable menu on Login screen and then to enable it after login.

You can disable menu by injecting `MenuController` and then use:

```
  import {NavController, MenuController} from 'ionic-angular';



  ionViewDidEnter() {
    //to disable menu, or
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    // to enable menu.
    this.menu.enable(true);
}
```

Comment: Hi Boris, Does disabling a Menu hides the menu toggle button at the same time ? Not sure .. Need to experiment. However, thanks for sharing the idea.

Comment: Hi @DigitalIQ I think not. I had similar problem in application on which I worked. I used code from my example to disable menu on some views so that user can't open menu by swiping. And I added navbar with menu toggle buttons only on views on which I wanted toggle button to show. Currently that is my solution for this, not sure is there any better.

Answer (score 1):

@Digital IQ, you have to set your login page as the rootPage in your existing app.ts file and use **MenuController** in login page to make menu enable **onPageDidLeave**. 
The example for this is available in [ionic conference app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app) where they have tutorial page before getting in to the actual application. Refer [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/app/pages/tutorial/tutorial.js) for menu control and [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/app/app.js) (line 50) to set the initial page.

Answer (score 0):

The above problem must have occurred because the user had surely logged in, but the changes i.e. setting it as the current user didn't take place in side menu page.

**For that you can use Events API**

**Events is a publish-subscribe style event system for sending and responding to application-level events across your app.**

For reference, go through the following answer-
[Ionic 3 refresh side menu after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211533/ionic-3-refresh-side-menu-after-login)

Comment: could you explain in detail  ? if possible !!

Answer (score -1):

kind Attn [vahid najafi & Aish123]

I tried something more easy and I found it working.

- I set the LogIn page as the root when the app first loaded - and I removed 'menuToggle' button from this template.
- Then I imported the **Component** I want to redirect on Log in
- I created a singIn function in LogInPage class as follows:

  signIn (){
      let navRef = this.app.getComponent('nav');
      navRef.setRoot(HelloIonicPage);
  }

and it worked like a charm