# Ionic 3 refresh side menu after login

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I need to display side menu items according to the role of the user. so I check in app.html if the page (role) is equal to logged in role. But it does not display items inside menu just after login but after refreshing the app using browser refresh button it displays correct items as it should. 
I guess the problem is ionic is caching the menu view if it is so how can I refresh the app for new menu items to display.

Every time I login with another user/role, it displays menu according to the previous user/role.

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor() {
    this.initializeApp();
    this.pages = [
                    { title: 'Home', component: 'HomePage', icon: 'home', role: 5 },
                    { title: 'Profile', component: 'ProfilePage', icon: 'person', role: 5 },
                    { title: 'Account', component: 'AccountPage', icon: 'home', role: 5 },
                    { title: 'Search Employee', component: 'AtlasemployeehomePage', icon: 'home', role: 4 }
                 ];

  }
```

**app.html**

```
<ion-list>
      <div *ngFor="let p of pages">
        <button menuClose ion-item *ngIf="p.role == role"  (click)="openPage(p)">
          <ion-icon  name="{{p.icon}}" style="margin-right:10%"></ion-icon> {{p.title}}
        </button>
      </div>

      <button menuClose ion-item (click)="presentLogout()">
        <ion-icon name="log-out" style="margin-right:10%"></ion-icon> Logout
      </button> 
    </ion-list>
```

I am setting the role variable according to the logged in user.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For that you can use [Events API](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/util/Events/)

> Events is a publish-subscribe style event system for sending and
> responding to application-level events across your app.

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// login.ts page (publish an event when a user is created)
constructor(public events: Events) {}
createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  this.events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}


// app.component.ts page (listen for the user created event after function is called)
constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
    // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
    console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Comment: @SagarKodte In one component you provide data to `events.publish()` and then in another component you access that data with `events.subscribe()`. In above example that data are `user` and `time`.

Comment: @TomislavStankovic Actually i want to use it for my login and signup. I want to update menus in sidebar after login or signup.

Comment: @Tomislav Stankovic can we use this for update login user details is it correct way to use this one.

Comment: @DenisBhojvani Yes, you can use it for that.

Comment: Events no loner use in Ionic 5