# How to update sidebar after login in ionic 3 without reopening app or refreshing in browser?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I created a login and sign up functionality in my ionic 3 app and it's also working properly but username after login not updating in sidebar instantly means i need to refresh the browser or i have to close the app and reopen the app after this username is showing in sidebar. But i want to show username instanlty after login for that for refreshing the page i added loader after login but doesn't work. I looked about event api in ionic 3 but not getting how to use. Please help. Below is my login.ts, app.component.ts, and app.html

login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage,Events, NavController, LoadingController NavParams,ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';
//import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import {
    AuthServiceProvider
} from "../../providers/auth-service/auth-service";

/**
 * Generated class for the LoginPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
  loading:any;
    responseData : any;
    userData = {"user":"","password":""};

  constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,public events: Events,private toastCtrl: ToastController,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public authService:AuthServiceProvider) {

        //this.title = this.navParams.get('title');
  }




  login(){
         var userMe = '';
      for(var key in this.userData) {
        if(key) {
          userMe = userMe + key + '=' + this.userData[key] + '&';
        }
        // console.log(this.userData[key]);
      }
     this.authService.postData(userMe,'user/login').then((result) => {
      this.responseData = result;
      //console.log(this.responseData);
      if(this.responseData.status == 1){
          this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: 'Waiting...'
        });
        this.loading.present();
      //console.log(this.responseData);
      localStorage.setItem('userStorage', JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
      this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
      this.loading.dismiss();
      ///this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
      }
    else{ 

       let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: this.responseData.message,
        duration: 3000,
        position: 'bottom'
      });

      toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
        console.log('Dismissed toast');
      });

      toast.present(); 
  }
    }, (err) => {
      // Error log
    });

  }


  pushSignup(){
    this.navCtrl.push(SignupPage);
  }
/*  pushHome(){
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);

  }*/

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');

  }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
// Angular
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

// RxJS
import { ReplaySubject } from "rxjs/ReplaySubject";
//import { ArrayObservable } from "rxjs/observable/ArrayObservable";

// Ionic
import { Nav,Events, Platform,NavController,LoadingController, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../providers/auth-service/auth-service';

// Ionic Native
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

// Pages
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

// Side Menu Component


@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController

    // Get the instance to call the public methods

    public rootPage: any = HomePage;
    loading: any;
    userStorage: any;
    hideMe:any;
    showMe = false;
    showButton : any=false;

    // Options to show in the SideMenuComponent


    private unreadCountObservable: any = new ReplaySubject<number>(0);

    constructor(public authService:AuthServiceProvider ,
                private platform: Platform,
                private statusBar: StatusBar,
                private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
                private event: Events,              
                private menuCtrl: MenuController,
                 public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
        this.initializeApp();
        this.profileName();

    }



    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
            this.splashScreen.hide();



        });

        // Change the value for the batch every 5 seconds
        setInterval(() => {
            this.unreadCountObservable.next(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
        }, 5000);

    }

     openMenu() {
   this.menuCtrl.open();
 }

 closeMenu() {
   this.menuCtrl.close();
 }

 toggleMenu() {
   this.menuCtrl.toggle();
 }
 login(){
    this.nav.push(LoginPage);
 }

  logout() {
        this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: 'Waiting...'
        });
        this.loading.present();
        localStorage.clear();
        this.showMe = false;

         this.loading.dismiss();

  }

  profileName(){
    if (this.userStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userStorage'))) {
        this.showMe = true;
        this.showButton = true;
    }
    else{
        this.showMe = false;
    }



  }


}
```

app.html for sidebar

```
<ion-menu [content]="myNav">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="item item-avatar" style="padding: 25px;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
            <img src="//ionicframework.com/img/docs/spengler.jpg">
            <h5 *ngIf="showMe == true" class="after-login">{{userStorage.data.surname}}</h5>
            <!-- <h6 *ngIf="showMe == true" class="before-login">Please Login.</h6> -->
            <!-- <p>Nine Inch Nails</p> -->
    </div>
    <ion-item *ngIf="showMe == false" menuClose detail-none (click)="login()">Login</ion-item>
    <ion-item menuClose detail-none (click)="">My Business</ion-item>
    <ion-item menuClose detail-none (click)="">Package</ion-item>
    <ion-item menuClose detail-none (click)="">Wallet</ion-item>
    <ion-item menuClose detail-none (click)="">Invite Friends</ion-item>
    <ion-item menuClose detail-none (click)="">Profile</ion-item>
    <ion-item menuClose detail-none (click)=""> FAQ</ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="showMe == true" menuClose detail-none (click)="logout()">Logout</ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Events API**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/)

> Events is a publish-subscribe style event system for sending and
>   responding to application-level events across your app.

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

// login.ts page (publish an event when a user is created)
constructor(public events: Events) {}
createUser(user) {
  console.log('User created!')
  this.events.publish('user:created', user, Date.now());
}


// app.component.ts page (listen for the user created event after function is called)
constructor(public events: Events) {
  events.subscribe('user:created', (user, time) => {
    // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
    console.log('Welcome', user, 'at', time);
  });
}
```

In one component you provide data to `events.publish()` and then in another component you access that data with `events.subscribe()`. In above example that data are `user` and `time`.

In your case

```
this._events.publish('user:signedIn',
              this.userData = 
 localStorage.setItem('userStorage', JSON.stringify(this.responseData)
 );
```

and then

```
_events.subscribe('user:signedIn', (userEventData) => {
    this.userData = localStorage.getItem('userStorage');
   });
```

Comment: I'm not getting how to use it in my code. I already commented on your this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45213110/5383669 post  to know how to use it..please can you help me with my code?