# Events in Ionic v4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using Ioni v4Beta and I'm traying to update the sidemenu when the user is login.

I search but the usual solution is use Events:

[Ionic 3 refresh side menu after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211533/ionic-3-refresh-side-menu-after-login)

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

But in the new version I don't find it, and I don't know how to do it

https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot, but I finally find how to import it:

```
import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';
```

Answer (score 0):

Example on how to do it with subjects:

```
export const someEvent:Subject = new Subject();

export class ReceivingClass implements OnDestroy, OnInit
{
   private someEventSubscription:Subscription;
   public OnInit():void{
      someEventSubscription = someEvent.subscribe((data) => console.log(data); 
   }

   public onDestroy():void{
     someEvent.unsubscribe();
   }
}

export class SendingClass implements OnInit
{
   public OnInit():void{
        setTimeout(() => {
            someEvent.next('hi');
        }, 500);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that Ionic v4 events will be deprecated soon?

I was also trying to update the sidemenu when a user logs in as well, so i tried using: `import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';`

However I got a warning referring me to this link https://angular.io/guide/observables#basic-usage-and-terms which I failed to follow because am not that familiar with observables.

After much research I found that I can still use events but I had to import them from angular's router directive.

This was my code before:

`/* import was */
import { Events } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';//ignore this import if doesn't apply to your code`

```
 /* inside the class */
  constructor(
  private events: Events,
  private storage: Storage 
  ) {

    this.events.subscribe("updateMenu", () => {

      this.storage.ready().then(() => {
        this.storage.get("userLoginInfo").then((userData) => {

          if (userData != null) {

            console.log("User logged in.");
            let user = userData.user;
            console.log(user);
          }
          else {
            console.log("No user found.");
            let user = {};
          }

        }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error);
              });

      }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error);
              });

    });

  }
```

changes i made that actually got my code working and deprecation warning gone:

```
/* import is now */
import { Router,RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';//ignore this import if it does't apply to your code
```

Rest of code

```
constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public storage: Storage
  ){

    this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
        this.storage.ready().then(() => {
          this.storage.get("userLoginInfo").then((userData) => {

              if (userData != null) {
                /*console.log("User logged in.");*/
                let user = userData.user;
                /*console.log(this.user);*/
              }
              else {
                /*console.log("No user found.");*/
                let user = {};
              }

            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error);
              });

        }).catch((error)=>{
          console.log(error);
        });

      });

}
```

I got the idea after seeing this https://meumobi.github.io/ionic/2018/11/13/side-menu-tabs-login-page-ionic4.html. I hope my answer can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to resolve the issue

1. import events in login page and in sidemenu view
2. In login page, after login success do your logic to publish the events.

   for eg:

   ```
   this.authService.doLogin(payload).subscribe((response) => {
     if (response.status) {
        this.storage.set('IS_LOGGED_IN', true);
        this.events.publish('user:login');
     } 
   }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
   });
   ```
3. In sidemenu view, create a listener to watch the events 'user:login'

   for eg:

   ```
   this.menus = [];

   // subscribe events
   this.events.subscribe('user:login', () => {
     // DO YOUR LOGIC TO SET THE SIDE MENU
     this.setSidemenu();
   });

   // check whether the user is logged in or not
   checkIsUserloggedIn() {
      let isLoggedIn = false;
      if (this.storage.get('IS_LOGGED_IN') == '' || 
          this.storage.get('IS_LOGGED_IN') == null || 
          this.storage.get('IS_LOGGED_IN') == undefined) {
         isLoggedIn = false;
      } else {
         isLoggedIn = true;
      }
      return isLoggedIn;
   }

   // to set your sidemenus
   setSidemenu() {
      let isUserLoggedIn = this.checkIsUserloggedIn();
      if(isUserLoggedIn) {
         this.menus = ['Home', 'Aboutus', 'Contactus', 'My Profile', 'Logout'];
      } else {
         this.menus = ['Login', 'Home', 'Aboutus', 'Contactus'];
      }
   }
   ```